# DoubleAnimation completed event not firing

Tags: c#, wpf

Okay, so I'm working on a project where we have all sorts of animations, and of those is giving me a headache. Specifically the one with removing UIElement from a grid. The animation does occur, but the element isn't physically removed. Here is the code we're using for removing:

```
    public static void RemoveChildAnimate(UIElement child, Grid grid)
    {
        DoubleAnimation an = new DoubleAnimation(1.0, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        child.BeginAnimation(btnDugmeTemp.OpacityProperty, an);

        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation(1.0, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        da.Completed += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { grid.Children.Remove(child); };

        ScaleTransform rt = new ScaleTransform();
        child.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        child.RenderTransform = rt;
        rt.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, da);
        rt.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, da);
    }
```

btnDugmeTemp code:

```
public partial class btnDugmeTemp : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler click;

    public btnDugmeTemp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.gdMain.MouseDown += gdMain_MouseDown;
    }

    void gdMain_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (click != null)
        {
            DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation(1.0, 0.95, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
            da.AutoReverse = true;
            ScaleTransform rt = new ScaleTransform();
            this.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            this.RenderTransform = rt;
            rt.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, da);
            rt.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, da);
            click(this, null);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("btnImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(btnDugmeTemp));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty textProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("btnText", typeof(string), typeof(btnDugmeTemp));


    public ImageSource btnImage 
    {
        get { return this.Image.Source; }
        set { this.Image.Source = value; }
    }

    public string btnText 
    {
        get { return this.Text.Content.ToString(); }
        set { this.Text.Content = value; }
    }

    public Brush btnBackColor
    {
        get { return this.gdMain.Background; }
        set { this.gdMain.Background = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `btnDugmeTemp`?

Comment: It's a User Control, i'll add the code.